# How to specifiy a formula for combined linear and sigmoid function

Tags: r, curve-fitting, sigmoid

There is a dataframe `df_heat` with `heat_output` over `temp`. As a first approximation you may fit the curve with two linear model and one breaking point:

`lm(data = df_heat, heat_output ~ temp + I(pmax(17-temp, 0)))`

[image]

I like to fit a linear model for low temperatures and and a sigmoid function for higher temperatures like suggested in [this paper](https://www.ffegmbh.de/download/informationen/583_slp_gas_weiterentwicklung/Studie_Weiterentwicklung-SLP-Gas_FfE.pdf) (german). The breaking point can be a fixed value at 5 °C.

[image]

How can I specify this formula in R?

Answer (score 1):

A model is proposed below. The equation involves four parameters a,c,tc and lambda.
The shape of the curve is controled by the parameter lambda.
Non-linear regression can be used to evaluate the four parameters and fit to data.

[image]

Comment: That looks promising. Bonus question: Do you know how to translate that to an `R` formula? I guess somehow `nls` for a nonlinear modell and `SSlogis` for the automatic evaluation of the parameter?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with the software R. I have my own softwares (not commercial). I suppose that R can do that as well as other commercial softwares. The main difficulty is the initial rough evaluation of the parameters which are required to start the iterative calculus. This depends a lot of the kind of data ( distribution, magnitude, scatter,..) . You should try with your own data and see.